# Как создать запрос SELECT, который выводит максимальное суммарное значение?

Tags: mysql

| id | q1 | w |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 2 | A | 5 |
| 3 | B | 10 |
| 4 | B | 9 |
| 5 | B | 2 |
| 6 | C | 2 |

Как создать запрос SELECT, который выводит максимальное суммарное значение `w`, по группировке `q`, чтобы результат был `B = 21`.

Comment: Посчитайте все суммарные значения, отсортируйте по убыванию, возьмите первое.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name`
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    q1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    w  INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `table_name`
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 2),
    (2, 'A', 5),
    (3, 'B', 10),
    (4, 'B', 9),
    (5, 'B', 2),
    (6, 'C', 2)
;

SELECT `q1`, SUM(`w`) AS `sum` FROM `table_name` GROUP BY `q1` ORDER BY `sum` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/040a78/2

Comment: А почему не возможно **select max(sum(w)) from table_name group by q1** .Я смотрю обучающее видео ,где так делают. Но в mysql  multirow function -вложеннось функций не возможна?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛучко, покажите видео.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDiy-LLV02E   2мин20 сек

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛучко, там есть копирование со временем сразу: https://youtu.be/aDiy-LLV02E?t=140. Будет время — гляну.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛучко, там же Oracle SQL ...